# SharePoint 2010 Document library versions comment

Tags: version-control, sharepoint-2010

I would like to force users to add their comments before checking-in document.
When a user selects Check-in, the default popup page will show in order to select version and write comments, but comments field is not mandatory, can we make it as a required field??

Answer (score 5):

You could do it via EventReceiver:

```
public class EventReceiver1 : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    public override void ItemCheckingIn(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemCheckingIn(properties);
        string comment = (string)properties.AfterProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckincomment"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comment))
        {
            properties.ErrorMessage = "Comment empty";
            properties.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```