# sharepoint event Receiver to make check in comments mandatory

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a question about SharePoint event receivers.  I would like to deploy an event receiver to make check in comments mandatory on a SharePoint 2013 Library like the one in this post: [SharePoint 2010 Document library versions comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715038/sharepoint-2010-document-library-versions-comment).

Does the event receiver need to be deployed via Central Administration or at the farm level or can a Collection Site Owner apply it directly to the site with SharePoint Designer?

I do not have access to Central Administration.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: [SharePoint StackExchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013, you can create Remote Event Receivers to handle ItemAdding and ItemUpdating events. You can build a SharePoint app to implement Remote Event Receivers. To know more about how to create a remote event receiver, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043(v=office.15).aspx

This way, you can allow Site Owner to deploy the custom SharePoint app to their sites.